# How can I start my Printapp from my other app if Printapp is NOT running on Android 8.1?

Tags: android

I am starting my Printapp from my other app at onCreate. How can i check the running status of my Printapp before i start it. If the printapp is already running, i don't want it to start.

```
    public void printAppAutoStart() {
        Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              
                Intent intent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.PrintApp");
                if (intent != null) {
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        },5000);
    }
```